# How to convert SMT(containing boolean and bounded int variables) constraints to CNF

Tags: z3

My applicant is originally a SAT problem. Now, I'm trying to do some extension which requires to use some int variables. So the problem becomes a SMT problem. But I encountered a performance problem when using z3 to solve it. As the int variable is bounded (less than 100), it's viable to convert it to a pure SAT problem.

Does anyone know how to apply this tactic in z3 c++ interface?
Or can I use z3 to convert the SMT constraints to SAT formulas firstly and then
try other SAT solvers?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you represent your problem in a bit vector formula, e.g. QF_ABV, it will be automatically flattened into propositional formula, and solved using a SAT solver. For example, you can represent your less-than-100 integer variables as a bit vectors of 7 bits.

Apart from bit vector, conversion from SMT to SAT will not boost your performance (otherwise SMT would not exist). Because SAT solver is only good at case analysis, and theory-specific decision procedures, e.g. simplex-based algorithms for linear arithmetic, are much more efficient in constraint solving.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! The performance is definitely improved after using bv variable to replace the int variable.

Comment: Do you know any tool to convert a constraint set containing boolean and bit-vector variables to a pure SAT problem?

Comment: AFAIK, converting to CNF is state-of-the-art for bit-vector, but I'm not aware of any tool that outputs the converted CNF into a file. Maybe you can hack stp solver to do this. https://sites.google.com/site/stpfastprover/ . Also check its paper http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1770421

Comment: @sean unsure. I saw that some smt solver works only through converting smt to sat. Also things cuda or fpga exists only for sat solving.

Comment: @DingbaoXie there are some tools for converting a verilog program into an unoptimized dimacs output for sat solvers.

Answer (score 0):

The yices SMT solver supports conversion from SMT constraints into SAT if Bitvectors are used. Use (export-to-dimacs "myfile.cnf") in SMT problem sheet and run yices with `--logic=QF_BV option`.

Comment: As far as I can tell this doesn't work.  `yices`, unlike `yices-smt2`, consumes the yices language instead of smtlib.  Did I miss something?